# javascript filter edit and save array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following sample data.

```
var data = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct1",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103 
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 2,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103 
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 3,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2016-07-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103 
}]
```

I would like to find a specific element based on the index and then edit a key and then append it to an existing variable.  What is the best way to do this, I've played with the .map and .filter options, but then I can't just return the edited element that matches when using .map.

Some things I've tried:

```
 //save the changes on the passed in item
 let transUpdate = trans.map(item => {
    if (item.transid === indexTransId) {
      return Object.assign({}, item, { notes: indexNote })
    }
    return item //if non matched item then just return the default 
 })
```

This one kind of works, but it returns a variable (transUpdate) that has all 
the elements from the trans array. I only want the matching transid for indexTransId and I want to append it to transUpdate.  If I return nothing by default on a non transid match I get an error.  If I return null by default then I get an empty object, but I would like to simply include only the matched transid.

I'm sure there are several ways to do this and I could use loops and ifs, but I'm interested in some of the more elegant ways to accomplish this with the ES6 syntax.

Comment: What is `indexTransId`?

Comment: Please provide an example input argument and what the output should be (not in words, but in code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append to `transUpdate`, you need indeed to use `filter`. Assuming you have a given `indexTransId` and `indexNode`, it would look like this:

```
transUpdate.push(...trans.filter(item => item.transid === indexTransId)
                          .map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { notes: indexNote })));
```

Note that if you do `Object.assign(item, { notes: indexNote })` you will mutate the original `item`: this would be a side-effect and not in line with *functional programming*.

#### Only adding new `transid` values:

In comments you added a specification: `transUpdate` should not get the same `transid` twice, but in that case update that record.

For that purpose an array is not that suitable. You could use a `Map` instead. You would declare it as follows:

```
transUpdate = new Map;
```

Then you can update it like so:

```
trans.filter(item => item.transid === indexTransId)
     .map(item => transUpdate.set(indexTransId, 
                  Object.assign({}, item, { notes: indexNote })));
```

To get the values from `transUpdate` in an array format, do:

```
[...transUpdate.values()]
```

Comment: This worked with the following change: push(...trans.filter(item => item.transid === indexTransId)
                          .map(item => Object.assign(item, { notes: indexNote })));  but I want to only append new indexTransids, so if the indexTransId exists already in transUpdate I want to edit it, not add another record.

Comment: I've tried this:  transUpdate = Object.assign({},transUpdate,...trans.filter(item => item.transid === indexTransId)
                          .map(item => Object.assign(item, { notes: indexNote }))); but that doesn't append but overrides the previous value.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please make sure to update your question to add the requirement that `transUpdate` should only get one object per `transid` value. See also my remark about the order of arguments in `Object.assign`.